# ProgressBar is getting invisible before load map completely

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm loading my markers(clustering) from a json and it's working.
But the markers is not so fast to render. My solution is show the progressbar while the markers is loading.
But the problem is that the progressbar is gone before the render.

I'm using the AsyncTask to render and I am adding the marker in the onProgressUpdate.

```
    public class GetMarkersAsync extends AsyncTask<String, HistoricoTO, List<HistoricoTO>> {

        private final static String OBTER = "http://10.0.0.65/Service.asmx/getEnvios";
        GoogleMap map;
        private Activity activity;
        private ProgressBar progressBar;

        public GetMarkersAsync (GoogleMap map, Activity activity) {
            this.map = map;
            this.activity = activity;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
   progressBar = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected List<HistoricoTO> doInBackground(String... params) {

            WebService ws = new WebService();

            String response = ws.makeRequest(OBTER);

            List<HistoricoTO> listaHistoricos = new ArrayList<HistoricoTO>();

            try {
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
                HistoricoTO historico;
                JSONObject jsonObject;

                for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                    jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    historico = new HistoricoTO();
                    historico.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    historico.setLatitude(jsonObject.getDouble("latitude"));
                    historico.setLongitude(jsonObject.getDouble("longitude"));

                    listaHistoricos.add(historico);

                    publishProgress(historico);
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return listaHistoricos;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(HistoricoTO... historicos) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(historicos);

            drawMarker(this.map, historicos[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HistoricoTO> historicoTOs) {
            super.onPostExecute(historicoTOs);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)

        }

        private void drawMarker(GoogleMap gmap, HistoricoTO historicoTO)
        {

            MyItem offsetItem = new MyItem(historicoTO.getLatitude(), historicoTO.getLongitude(), historicoTO);

           MainActivity.mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().addMarker(mo);

          MainActivity.mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);

           gmap.addMarker(mo);
        }

    }
```

PS: It's working, the ProgressBar is showing, but the problem is that the markers only shows when I "move" the map ou touch.

Comment: Try to draw the markers in onPostExecute()

Comment: I have thought about it. But for example, when I have 5000 markers, it will not be so fast. Why doesn't OnProgressUpdate the best way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

every time you add a new marker, invalidate map again.
so it will draw your item on map.

> map.invalidate()

Comment: I am calling the map invalidate on my drawmarker method. But the application became slowly. I am testing the invalidate on my postexecute.

Comment: try it with a limit! for example every 20 object, call invalidate once ! @Teste